# Transformation using pyspark or sparksql

Tags: azure, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying some way to get the newoutput column with logic whenever I divide the column E/C i.e 40/5 it give 8 as a divided and I need to take column E digit(excluding end zero) * by dividend. i.e 4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4.

Please find screen shot of a data frame or table.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`array_repeat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_repeat.html?highlight=array_repeat) and [`array_join`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.array_join.html?highlight=array_join) after identifying the value to repeat and number of times to repeat.

## Working Example

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_repeat, array_join, col as c, floor, lit, when
from pyspark.sql import Column

data = [(5, 40, ), (10, 80, ), (20, 120, )]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ("C", "E", ))

def repetition(col_c: Column, col_e: Column) -> Column:
    times_to_repeat = floor(c("E") / c("C")).cast("int")
    value_to_repeat = when(c("E") % lit(10) == 0, (c("E") / lit(10)).cast("int")).otherwise(c("E"))
    value_repeat = array_repeat(value_to_repeat, times_to_repeat)
    return array_join(value_repeat, ",")

df.withColumn("Newoutput", repetition(c("C"), c("E"))).show(100, False)
```

### Output

```
+---+---+-----------------+
|C  |E  |Newoutput        |
+---+---+-----------------+
|5  |40 |4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4  |
|10 |80 |8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8  |
|20 |120|12,12,12,12,12,12|
+---+---+-----------------+
```

Comment: Hello Snithish , Thankyou I am also almost on the way array_join I forget to use now it is working fine.